# Is there another way to click on a menu item with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

Friends try anyway but it is not being possible to click on the Gestão de Materiais Menu item. One situation I need is to scroll this menu to view and click on the item menu. But I'm not sure why he is clicking on the menu item below
I tried using SitePrism and pure capybara but it is not possible.
When it runs, it is clicking on ***Gestao de Empresas***

***capybara:***
find(:xpath, "//div[contains(text(),'Gestão de Materiais')]" ).click
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="TBB_tbm2"]/div[3]/div[2]').click

***site Prism:***
element :item_mn_gestao_materiais, :xpath,  "//div[contains(text(),'Gestão de Materiais')]"
element :item_mn_gestao_materais,  :css,    '#TBB_tbm2 img[src*=articoli64]'
def cadastra_diametro_material_ativo
item_mn_gestao_materiais.click
end
[image]

Menu Principal





Modulo Básico





Gestão Instalações





Gestão de Materiais

<div

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried and which element is it clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in trying Capybara and SitePrism, SitePrism uses capybara so if capybaras click doesn't work for you then SitePrism isn't going to either.

Given the visible info, if I was writing this I'd write

```
find('#TBB_tbm2 > div', text: 'Gestão de Materiais').click
```

following the two rules

1. Don't use XPath unless absolutely necessary
2. Write the minimal selector necessary

beyond that it's impossible to go any further with the current information

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work!.. It's picking up the 'Gestão de Empresas' menu item. This component has a highlight, is it due to this? 
I don't understand why this started happening now! He is clicking on the wrong menu item even though the mapping is correct.

Comment: @Elis Capybara clicks at the location the element you tell it to click on is located. If it really is clicking on the wrong element there could be a number of reasons. 1.  the layout of the element is larger than it should be, and isn't handling mouse events so they fall through to an element below. 2. The page is animating so it's clicking where the element was but it's moved in between and now a different element is there. 3. The screen size is too small to properly show the page so elements are overlapping. 4. The page has a bug in it

Comment: Dude, you can't get enough of being so good?...lol You're actually correct, I ran it on a bigger monitor and it passed!!..

Comment: With this configuration and on the 15.6 monitor it crashes, but on the larger monitor it passes.                                                                                                                            Capybara.page.current_window.resize_to(1360, 768) Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize